# Finding Expectation of a Stochastic Differential Equation Solution

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Been stuck on trying to solve the following SDE:

\begin{equation}
    dX_t = \left(X_t + t^2\right)dt + e^{W_t}\,dW_t
\end{equation}
Where $W_t$ represents the standard Brownian motion and $X_0 = 1$

My attempt so far

> Using ito Lemma, $dX_t = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial^2W_t}\right)dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_t} dW_t$
>
> I equated the terms giving me
> \begin{align}
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial^2W_t} = X_t + t^2 &= f + r^2 \tag{1}\label{1} \\
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_t} &= e^{-W_t} \tag{2}\label{2}
> \end{align}
> Then I used separation of variables on equation (\ref{2})
> \begin{align}
> \int df &= \int e^{-W_t} dW_t \\
> f &= -e^{-W_t} + a(t)
> \end{align}
>
> Then using this equation of $f$ I found the following derivatives:
> \begin{align}
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = a'(t) &&
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_t} = e^{W_t} &&
> \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial^2W_t} = -e^{-W_t}
> \end{align}
> Which I then substituted into (\ref{1}), giving:
> \begin{align}
> a'(t) +-\frac{1}{2}e^{-W_t} &= f+t^2 \quad \text{Substituting our equation for $f$}\\
> a'(t) - a(t) -t^2 +\frac{1}{2}e^{-W_t} &= 0
> \end{align}

From here I am not too sure how to solve $a(t)$ or even if that's what I need to find the solution. I have seen this method used in a simpler example but not sure if it applies here.

My question actually asked me to find the expectation of $X_t$ but my thinking was, that I first must find the solution to the SDE to find the expectation.

EDIT: Following from Chaos's answer (??)

\begin{align}
    dY_t=e^{-t}t^2dt+e^{W_t-t}dW_t
\end{align}

Which solving gives:

\begin{equation*}
    Y_t = -e^{-t}\left(t^2+2t+2\right) + e^{W_t-t} + C_1
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    X_t = e^{W_t} + \frac{C_2}{e^{-t}} - t^2-2t-2
\end{equation*}

Using our initial condition:

$$X_0 = 1 + C_2 - 2 = 1 \implies C_2 = 2$$

Giving:

\begin{align*}
    E\left[X_t\right] = E\left[e^{W_t} + \frac{2}{e^{-t}} - t^2-2t-2\right]
    = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(e^{z} + \frac{2}{e^{-t}} - t^2-2t-2\right)\mathcal{F}(z)\;\text{d}{z}
\end{align*}
With $\mathcal{F}(x)$ being the pdf of $\mathcal{N}(0,t)$ distribution.

Comment: notice that all the terms in the integral but the first one do not depend on $z$ and could be pulled out of the integral. You are then left with an integral that can be solved explicitly (e.g. moment generating function of a Gaussian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y_t:=e^{-t}X_t$, and using the Itô formula compute its stochastic differential as

$$dY_t=e^{-t}dX_t-e^{-t}X_tdt$$
now replace $dX_t$ with the expression you are given.

At this point you will notice that you no longer have an SDE but rather the differential form of a Itô process,
$$dY_t=e^{-t}t^2dt+e^{W_t-t}dW_t.$$

Now just integrate both sides and proceed to obtain $X_t$, from there I am sure you'll manage to obtain the expectation by yourself.